# How exactly are tasklets scheduled internally?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

I know that Tasklets are deferred interrupt handlers are are executed in interrupt context besides they have the highest priority (most certainly above user processes).

However if we have multiple Tasklets with a lot of work to be done, how are these Tasklets scheduled ? What is the order in which they are executed ?

Comment: What's the context? The Linux kernel?

Comment: Yes, in the context of Linux Kernel.

Comment: That's a programming question then, better suited for [so] as [unix.se] is a site for users and administrators. I'm flagging for migration there (do not repost).

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a very general question about a rather complex topic. (you might also want to specify your kernel version and whether you are using the RT-preempt patch.)  I found this page to contain a pretty good description of tasklets.

[tasklets](http://www.makelinux.com/books/lkd2/ch07lev1sec3)

Hope that helps.  But I guess the quick answer to "how are they scheduled" is first-come-first-serve within the softirq-tasklet thread.

Michael